# Automatically remove Sonarqube branch projects when git branch merged / removed

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We currently have a jenkins pipeline using `Multibranch Workflow plugin`. Each git branch execute a sonarqube analysis creating a sonarqube project using the  `sonar.branch` property. This is very useful because each branch is being analyzed before merge it, the problem appear when a branch is merged with master and disappear on GIT, the project continues on sonarqube and need to be deleted manually. 
Is There a way to do it automatically? or any other recomendation?

Comment: have you got the solution if so, please share comprehensively

Comment: No yet, the only solution found is to use commercial solutions. I'm still looking for a different solution for community version.

Comment: I have found one solution and posted as an answer below, check if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a method as below, to do the job and then call the method whenever you need according to your need or on some event like git branch merged/removed, etc.

```
def deleteSonarProject() {
    def sonarToken = "-your admin credential token generate it from sonarServer-"
    def url = "http://yourBaseURL:portNumber/api/projects/delete"
    sh "curl -u ${sonarToken}: ${url} -d 'project=projectKey'"
}
```

Comment: interesting. I should launch this script when the branch has been deleted o merged. I will review that solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Yes, that is the best option i has found. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The best way to remove SonarQube branch projects is to not push them to the server in the first place. Here are your options:

- use [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) to spot issues directly in your IDE
- if you're using GitHub, use the [GitHub Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin)
- if you're using BitBucket, use [this plugin](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash) or [this one](https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin)

At SonarSource, we use SonarLint and the GitHub Plugin on a daily basis. One last solution is to delete manually the project using the [api/projects/delete](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/projects/delete) web service.

Comment: If you use a continuous integration system like Jenkins, when you create a branch on git from master the jenkinsfile it is also copied, avoid sonarque analysis imply modify this file. In some cases the developer forget this step.

Comment: We have the same "problem" with Travis. That's why our script do some conditional checks (are we on master branch or not) before running  the SonarQube analysis.

Comment: I want my branch to be on sonar but I would like them to be deleted when branch is merged / deleted.
So you use a git hook to call sonar api / delete on branch merge / delete ?

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using Bitbucket Server and the Sonar for Bitbucket Server add-on, there's an automatic way to perform this cleanup.  To enable this setting from Bitbucket Server, follow the 3 steps shown in the screenshots below.

[Screenshot of 3 steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqZEZ.png)

Comment: Perhaps is the best solution if you can buy the plugin,  it is not always possible.

Comment: if you cannot invest 10 bucks / 10 users you probably also should'nt be investing time into continuous integration / code QA. Extreme programming and a very simple SCM is probably all you need for such a project. Just sayian. SonarQube and the likes make sense in business-oriented teams only - for everything else a simple cronjob might do the trick.

Comment: My case is different, the number of users for bitbucket is large (+2000) but the number of sonarqube users is small (less than 100). Perhaps a custom scheduled task that check projects and repositories is a solution.